# block specific user to send mail

Tags: sendmail

I am using `sendmail` in RHEL 5. I have three mail accounts for the users jack, bob and 
alice. I want to make sure that user bob can send mail to alice but jack can't send mail to alice. But user jack can send mail to bob. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you just want to block Jack → Alice, or do you want to block Jack → Everyone but Bob? And do you want to block jack@externalsystem.example.com from sending to Alice too?

Comment: Hi Mattdm, I want to restrict user jack to send mail to alice. But everyone can send mail to user alice except user jack...

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to set up a .procmailrc file in Alice's home directory to throw away mail from Jack (see "man procmail").

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this link http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/sendmail-block-email-to-particular-user-on-same-domain-676596/

That might work for you too.

Ismael Casimpan :)